# Set up SQL Server 2008, how do I access it from C# using SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express, and I'm trying to access it from C#.

I'm not so sure I set it up right in SQL Server Management Studio. I have a password, and a .sdf file. Nothing is in the database at the moment. Here's my snippet of code in C#

```
SqlConnection userSqlData = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost;database=UserData;Password=Mine;connection timeout = 10");

try
{   
    userSqlData.Open();     
}
catch
{     
    MessageBox.Show("Failed");     
}
```

The connection always times out. Obviously I've set something up wrong here. How do I get it to connect to database on local computer?

Comment: A .sdf file is a database file for SQL Server **Compact Edition** (CE) - **not** SQL Server Express......

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to SQL Server express ;) You connect to the default instance. Express is a named instance.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

has all kinfds of examples, including for express databases.

Comment: i don't even know how to set up an instance of sql express. i'm looking everywhere in the config files and i don't know how to set it up

Comment: Sql express is per definition a named instance.

Answer (score -1):

The default connection string for SQL Server looks like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You need the named instance in `Data Source`.  You also need to specify the `User Id` of the user you're authenticating as, not just the password. 
Here's a good resource for additional options:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: -1. He uses express, there it looks different ;) You miss the named instance.